# Arranging $3n$ married couples into groups of $3$ so that no spouses are in the same group

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways can $3n$ married couples be arranged into groups of $3$ people so that spouses are never in the same group.

I interpreted this task to mean the order of the groups doesn't matter, that is, the groups aren't listed and same people together in all groups counts as one arrangement, but I got lost without having an anchor to divide cases so as to use the inclusion-exclusion formula. Here is my idea in the case if the order doesn't matter. I hope somebody could verify it and give me an advice on how to deal with the irrelevant order.

---

Let $S_k$ denote the set of all groupings into $3$ such that there is a married couple in the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ group. We can choose one of the $3n$ couples and $3^{\mathrm{rd}}$ person among $6n-2$ others. We can, then, arrange the remaining $6n-3$ people in $(n-1)!S(6n-3,3)$ ways, where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind. Hence, $|S_k|=3n(6n-2)(n-1)!S(6n-3,3)$.

We need to compute $\left|\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k\right)\right|=n!S(6n,3)-\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k\right|.$ We shall use the inclusion-exclusion formula: $$\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k\right|=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}\sum_{1\le j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_i\le n}\left|\bigcap_{\ell=1}^iS_{j_\ell}\right|.$$

In each of the inner sums, there are $\binom{n}i$ summans for different choices of $i$ groups containing $i$ couples that can, again, be chosen in $\binom{n}i$ ways and permuted in $i!$ ways. Then, we choose the $3^{\mathrm{rd}}$ persons among the remaining $(6n-2i)$ in $\binom{6n-2i}i$ ways and place them in the $i$ groups in $i!$ ways. The rest of the $6n-3i$ people can be arranged into $n-i$ groups of $3$ into $(n-i)!S(6n-3i,3)$.

I believe, this all should yield $$\left|\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k\right)^c\right|=n!S(6n,3)+\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}i P^n_iP^{6n-2i}_i(n-i)!S(6n-3i,3),$$ where $P^n_k$ is the number of $k$ permutations of a set of $n$ elements.

Comment: You should be able to apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. First find number of ways where at least one of the married couples is in the same group: ${3n \choose 1} {6n-2 \choose 1} \cdot \frac{(6n-3)!}{ (2n-1)! \cdot (3!)^{2n-1}} - {3n \choose 2} ...+ ...$